# Need to add 'popping up help window' function to About Dialog

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I've designed my own help content for my RCP. And the pop up help window works properly for other common dialog, except the Help->About Dialog.
My purpose is once the user clicked the help button, the help window should be popped up successfully just like what eclipse does.

I set an help listener for the aboutAction in my code. Unfortunately it does not work.

```
    aboutAction = ActionFactory.ABOUT.create(getWindow());
    WorkbenchHelpSystem.getInstance().setHelp(aboutAction, IWorkbenchHelpContextIds.HELP_CONTENTS_ACTION);
    aboutAction.setImageDescriptor(IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.getImageDescriptor(IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_DEFAULT_PROD));
    aboutAction.setHelpListener(new HelpListener()
    {
        public void helpRequested(HelpEvent event)
        {
            getWindow().getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp();
        }
    });
    menu.add(aboutAction);
    menu.add(new GroupMarker("group.about.ext"));
```

I am just a beginner in eclipse rcps. Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how something is implemented in Eclipse (in your case the about dialog) you could use the **Plug-in Spy**. Look [in this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011216/how-is-eclipse-line-number-status-line-contribution-item-implemented/8078652#8078652) for further details on how to use the plug-in spy.

Comment: I've tried to add the help listener to other re-write dialog. All of them works fine. The help windows pops up successfully.  While actually i don't know which dialog does the AboutAction use, so i could not re-write a new one for it using. Therefore i tried to add the help listener to the aboutAction itself. Unfortunately it does not work. Now i want to know the reasons why the listener lose efficacy. Or point out the default dialog which the aboutAction used might be helpful too.