# Display ValidationMessage at the Status area

Tags: swt, jface

How to display the Validationmessages and errors in the status area.(bottom left).

As i was new to the SWT can any once help me

Comment: Stats area of what? A dialog? Which type of dialog? Please show us the relevant code and explain what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `IStatusLineManager` `setErrorMessage` method to do this in an editor or a view.

In an editor get the manager with:

```java
IStatusLineManager manager = getEditorSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager();
```

in a view use:

```java
IStatusLineManager manager = getViewSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager();
```

Then call

```java
manager.setErrorMessage("message");
```

or

```java
manager.setErrorMessage(image, "message");
```

If you are in a text editor derived from `TextEditor` you can use `IEditorStatusLine`. In your editor class you can get this with:

```java
IEditorStatusLine statusLine = getAdapter(IEditorStatusLine.class);
```

This has a `setMessage` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help.How to Set the Text to display at specific position.

Comment: All you can do is add additional contribution items to the status bar. You can only do this for an editor - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8011216/2670892)